# String Localisation Problem in Silverlight Application

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, localization

I have an odd problem in silverlight.  I use the following XAML to bind the content of a label to a double property in my viewmodel.

```
Content="{Binding FeePeriodActual, Mode=OneWay,StringFormat=\{0:c\}}"
```

However, the display string always shows the $ Dollar Currency symbol rather than the the £.  This is the same on the production server and the dev machine.  All localisation properties are set right on the webserver(s).  I can't see where to change it in the silverlight app.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the `Application_Startup` method in App.xaml.cs to look like this:-

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  Resources.Add("DefaultCulture", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

  this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
}
```

Now where you need culture specific formatting in bindings use:-

```
Content="{Binding FeePeriodActual, Mode=OneWay,StringFormat=\{0:c\}, ConverterCulture={StaticResource DefaultCulture}}"
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I can represent this in XAML, as doing in code seems to mess with the VS designer.....